# WPF Outlook Interop Integration (Getting Around Security Warning Popup)

Tags: c#, wpf, outlook

I'm trying to integrate our (C#) WPF application with 2007 Outlook Interop. I've got it working as it should, but I'm getting the security warning. I know that using Redemption is an option to "get around the bush," but I don't want to just get around the problem, I'd like to somehow allow access via credentials or something. This isn't an add-in. I'm simply using the interop to interact with the users client session of Outlook.

Is there anything that I can do to create some credentials that I can pass through from my app to prevent the security warning from showing up when my application is accessing the Outlook session?

Thanks!

Comment: What specifically are you looking to do with your Outlook integration?  The reason that I'm asking is because maybe the path to achieve your goal would be to integrate with Exchange/O365 instead

Comment: @KyleBurns A user is dragging an email onto my application and I'm parsing it and moving it into a subfolder with the intention of being able to go back and change category, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to disable the security prompt is to have an up-to-date AV app installed. If you cannot control the environment, then it is Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi) or Redemption (any language).

You can also move your Outlook related code to a COM addin (addins are trusted).

Comment: I don't want to disable the security prompt completely. That's not an option. There has to be a way to indicate an application is "fully trusted" or something, right? How do applications such as virus protectors accomplish this?

Comment: No, there is no such option. Antivirus apps do not use Outlook Object Model.

Comment: What do they use? They connect to the exchange itself?

Comment: The ones working on the client side use Extended MAPI, which is the native API used by Outlook itself.

Comment: Or they also install their Outlook addins which handle incoming messages.

Comment: So if I use Extended MAPI in my C#/WPF all, I can avoid this? Is that possible when using Interop?

Comment: No, Extended MAPI can only be used from C++ or Delphi. There is no Extended MAPI interop for .Net.